# Python folium: Present content dependent on fields=['id'] in GeoJsonPopup

Tags: python, gis, folium

I created a Map using python folium in jupyter lab. On the Map I display some geoJson-Files as shapes.

**What Works so far:**
The Shapes from the GeoJson file are displayed nicely on the map. I can change the color of the shapes based on a self generated style_function which checks feature['properties']['id'] to adjust the style type accordingly.
I'm also able to get a GeoJsonPopup on_click to a shape. The Popup shows *id* and the *content* of the *id* property of that shape.

```
geo_popup = folium.GeoJsonPopup(fields=['id'])
my_json = folium.GeoJson(file.path, style_function=style_function, popup=geo_popup)   
my_json.add_to(map)
```

**What I want:**
I want to display in the popup some content based on the *id*. Very basic Example: if *id* = 1 i want to display 'This is the region Alpha' or if *id* = 2 -> 'This area is beautiful'.
Alternatively, if that is not possible, I would like to present a Link in the Popup where i can Access a Page with a parameter to show dedicated content for that *id*.

**What I tried**
I tried to derive a class from folium.GeoJsonPopup and somehow write content to the render function. But, however, I don't really get how it works and therefor all I did wasn't successful. Probably I took somewhere the wrong path and the solution is pretty easy.

Thanks for advice!

Comment: Here is the [sample](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/GeoJsonPopupAndTooltip.ipynb) you need.

Comment: @r-beginners: Thank you, that indeed is interesting. But then, to display arbitrary Information in the Popup, I still need to merge that Information into the GeoJson providing the shapes first, right?

Answer (score 1):

I followed the linked [sample](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/GeoJsonPopupAndTooltip.ipynb) in the comment to the question. Therefore I had to add the needed dict entries to the the features properties.
Therefore I can link to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287157/add-properties-to-large-geojson) question. I used the .update from the solutions last comment to add the values.